# Relationship between these two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Let the Fibonacci sequence be given by $F_{1}=1, F_{2}=2$ and $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$.

Let the sequence $\{U_{n}\}$ be given by $U_{1}=0, ~U_{2}=-1$ and $~U_{n+2}= U_{n+1}+U_{n}+n-1$.

a) Give the relationship between $U_n$ and $F_n$.

b) Show that this relationship holds for all $n \ge 1$.

I'm stuck on part a. How do I find this?

Comment: What do you think you should do for a start? Try writing the sequences out for ten terms and see what empirical relationship you can guess and try to prove it

Comment: @insipidintegrator I tried to do this but I just cant recognise a pattern.

Comment: Okay so please edit the post and mention that you did this. Maybe write out both the series in the post.  Otherwise people will assume by reading your post that this is a low-quality post.

Comment: Tips: $n+(n+1)-(n+2)=n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship is $U_n = F_{n-1} - n$.

Note that for $U_1 = F_0 - 1 = 0$ and $U_2 = F_1 - 2 = -1$. By the way, in the problem information, they forget to give $F_0 = 1$.

And we have $$U_{n+2} - U_{n+1} - U_n = F_{n+1} - (n+2) - F_{n} + (n+1) - F_{n-1} + n \\ = -(n+2)+(n+1)+n=n-1$$